# UserRecoverableAuthException: intent not firing up

Tags: android, android-intent, oauth-2.0

I am trying to fire the window where the application asks the user
to give consent for the application to access user data via
GoogleAuthUtil.getToken().

However I cannot see the activity fired up from the UserRecoverableAuthException.

I've searched but not found any helpful posts that resolve this issue.

Anyone have any ideas? (the "Shoot2!" is printed out but nothing happens
in LogCat after that).

```
  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    System.out.println("HERE!!!");
    System.out.println(CalendarScopes.CALENDAR);

    new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {

      @Override
      protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

        try {
          System.out.println("Hello2!");
          String token = GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(EventsActivity.this, "jdoe@gmail.com", "oauth2:" + CalendarScopes.CALENDAR);
          System.out.println("token");
          System.out.println("Hello3!");
        } catch (GooglePlayServicesAvailabilityException playEx) {
          System.out.println("Shoot1!");
          playEx.printStackTrace();
        } catch (UserRecoverableAuthException recoverableException) {
          System.out.println("Shoot2!");
          Intent recoveryIntent = recoverableException.getIntent();
          recoveryIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_FROM_BACKGROUND);
          // Use the intent in a custom dialog or just startActivityForResult.
          startActivityForResult(recoveryIntent, 99);
        } catch (GoogleAuthException authEx) {
          System.out.println("Shoot3!");
          // This is likely unrecoverable.
          authEx.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException ioEx) {
          System.out.println("Shoot4!");
          ioEx.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;

      }
}.execute();
```

Comment: I also used codes like you and it used to work well. However it not run anymore few days ago. startActivityForResult(recoverableException.getIntent(),123) didn't fire authorization dialog up. And i also didn't figure it out. notice me if you find something. So good luck and be keep in touch

Answer (score 0):

I discovered in my case the Authorization intent wasn't been fired because I added singleInstance to the activity in the AndroidManifest.xml

Removing

```
android:launchMode = "singleInstance"
```

fixed this problem and a couple of other strange transition effects between activities.